# GRUB EFI issues

Tags: linux, boot, grub, bootloader

I have recently switched bootloader from BIOS to EFI. My GRUB has some issues:

- when I enter LUKS passphrase and then press 'Return', I don't see that (cursor doesn't move)
- Cyrillic text is not displayed (language‐related)
- installed theme is not used
- some glitches
- when I boot an OS, I don't see output so I don't know when to enter passphrase second time
- after I enter passphrase second time, newline is inserted in partition string (usually, in word "blocks", after "c" or "k")

How do I fix them?

Comment: How did you switch from BIOS to UEFI?

Comment: I removed my BIOS boot partition and created EFI system partition instead, and created *fallback path* bootx64.efi. If you can help me to install GRUB correctly, please do, because my computer reboots when EFI boot entries are added/removed.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: @gronostaj, Parabola GNU/Linux‐libre (based on Arch Linux). OpenRC iso to install GRUB, also with efi_no_storage_paranoia.